# How to calculate the multiplication factor for scroll speed on another element so that they both reach end at the same time (top of view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a sidebar scroll at a slower rate than the main content of the article, so that it will stay in view longer. The element will lock in when it hits the top the screen.

I've seen similar approaches to this, but they are usually based on fixed positioned elements.

See the JSFiddle example at the bottom to see how it is supposed to behave.

**HTML**

```
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    1
    <br />2
    <br />3
    <br />4
    <br />5
    <br />6
    <br />7
    <br />9
    <br />10
    <br />1
    <br />2
    <br />3
    <br />4
    <br />5
    <br />6
    <br />7
    <br />9
    <br />10
    <br />
    <br />4
    <br />5
    <br />6
    <br />7
    <br />9
    <br />10
    <br />
    <div class="data">
      0
    </div>
    <br /> END
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  display: block;
}
.main {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.container.fixed .sidebar {}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  min-height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var sb = $('.sidebar');
      var mn = $('.main');
      var cn = $('.container');
      var height = $(window).height();
      var mnStart = mn.offset().top;
      var mnHeight = mn.height();
      var sbHeight = sb.height();
      var sbLock = cn.height() - sb.height();
      var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
      var sbScroll = -(scrolled - mnStart) * ((height - mnHeight) / (height - sbHeight));
      if (scrolled >= mnStart && sbScroll <= sbLock) {
        sb.css({
          transform: 'translate3d(0,' + sbScroll + 'px,0'
        });
      } else if (scrolled < mnStart){
        sb.css({
          transform: 'translate3d(0,' + 0 + 'px,0'
        });
      } else if (sbScroll > sbLock){
        sb.css({
          transform: 'translate3d(0,' + sbLock + 'px,0'
        });         
      }
    });
  });
```

If you have a look at this fiddle [JSFiddle (short main content)](https://jsfiddle.net/yytnu3bw/1/) and compare it to this [JSFiddle (long main content)](https://jsfiddle.net/yytnu3bw/2/) you can see that the script doesn't really work well with the variation of the main content length.

I'm trying to figure out how i can calculate the multiplication factor i need in order to make the sidebar scroll smoothly until it reaches the same bottom position as the main content. as you can see in example 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the work on this from the beginning again and found a solution that fits my need.

Thought maybe others might take it to good use.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    1
    <br />2
    <br />3
    <br />4
    <br />5
    <br />6
    <br />7
    <br />8
    <br />9
    <br />10
    <br />11
    <br />12
    <br />13
    <br />14
    <br />15
    <br />16
    <br />17
    <br />18
    <br />19
    <br />20
    <br />21
    <br />22
    <br />23
    <br />24
    <br />25
    <br />26
    <br />27
    <br />28
    <br />29
    <br />END
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  display: block;
}

.main {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 8000px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.container.fixed .sidebar {}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  min-height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        slowScroll('.main','.sidebar');
    });
    function slowScroll(obj1, obj2) {
      var long, short;
      if ($(obj1).height() > $(obj2).height()) {
        long = $(obj1);
        short = $(obj2);
      } else {
        long = $(obj2);
        short = $(obj1);
      }
      var lHeight   = long.height(); // Height of longest element
      var sHeight   = short.height(); // Height of shortest element
      var sLock     = lHeight - sHeight; // What position from top the shortest element should lock in at
      var startPos  = long.offset().top; // The start position relevant to document (offset from top)
      var scrolled  = $(window).scrollTop(); // Current value scrolled from top
      var lScrolled = ((scrolled - startPos) >= 0) ? (scrolled - startPos) : 0;// Current value scrolled from start of longest element
      var scrollX   = sLock/lHeight; // Scroll multiplier
      var sPos  = ((lScrolled * scrollX) <= sLock) ? (lScrolled * scrollX) : sLock;// Scroll position for the shortest element
      short.css({transform: 'translate3d(0,' + sPos + 'px,0'});
    }
});
```

As far as I've testet it now it seems to work with the varying heights of both the main and sidebar element As you can see in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ata9t5n3/6/) here.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could get is this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
parallax();
});
function parallax(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.main').css('top',-(scrolled*0.1)+'px');
$('.sidebar').css('top',-(scrolled*0.2)+'px');
}
```

Keep in mind this is a very minimalist approach, but the sidebar stays in view for longer, you can play around with the functions parameters and see what happens, and yes, fixed css position or this will not work. This needs some css rules to look tidy, but the JS functionality works.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/NNwmRm

Another option would be to just set a timer on the sidebart and makle it fade in and out or transform after a given time and scroll position, like here:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PZQVOR

Comment: Thank you for your response.

As for the first option: Yes I can use fixed positioning to a certain degree, but would rather avoid this due to it's limitations. I've also looked into your option of setting a fixed multiplication factor, but the effect would vary too much from article to article.

Your second option with a what I assume is a "moving" sidebar, I'm not sure how it would solve my issue with sidebar content expanding outside of view, as this should become visible as the user scrolls down on the page.

Allthough I do not feel it solves any issues I appreciate the input.